# Why am I getting 403 for POST with DRF and rest_framework_api_key?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, api-key

I am getting a 403 response from the server in my new Django app. It is very simple. I don't even have models, I just want to return an audio file, but I want to do it through an API. Because of that, since I am not going to have users, I need an API key, and I found that I can use the Django REST framework and the REST framework API key modules. I have followed the quickstarts and can't seem to get a response. It was working before, but it was authenticating through CSRF, and like I said, it is going to be an API, so I won't have CSRF cookies.

Here is the view I am using:

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
def tts_view(request):
  data = request.POST

  voice_name = data.get("voice_name")
  text = data.get("text")

  if not voice_name or not text:
    return JsonResponse({"error": "Missing voice_name or text"}, status=400)

  return JsonResponse({"wav": text_to_wav(voice_name, text)}, status=200, safe=False)
```

The settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_api_key',
    'TTS',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey",
    ]
}
```

And the fetch (the API key is just a test, so it doesn't matter):

```js
fetch('/create-speech', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        voice_name: "es-US-Neural2-B",
        text: "Estoy feliz"
    }),
    headers: { 
        'Authorization': '0tSMNivu.f8DOBrHTTKfMQBGANNbjl5BJQcswN9ay',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then((resp) => {
    if (!resp.ok) throw Error(`${resp.statusText} - ${resp.status}`);
    return resp.json();
})
.then((wav) => {
    console.log('success');
});
```

I am doing the fetch in the console on the default page, which is not defined (like I said, I only want an API).

I have tried including `rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny` into `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`, but it doesn't work either.

I don't really know what else to do, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django REST Framework API Key docs](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#making-authorized-requests):

> By default, clients must pass their API key via the Authorization header. It must be formatted as follows:
>
> `Authorization: Api-Key <API_KEY>`

You're missing the `Api-Key`  part (notice the space between it and the `<API_KEY>` part). So your request should be:

```js
fetch('/create-speech', {
    ...
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Api-Key 0tSMNivu.f8DOBrHTTKfMQBGANNbjl5BJQcswN9ay',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
...
```

Comment: You are right! I was missing that. But it is still not working :(

Comment: Does it still 403? Any details in the response body?

Comment: Still 403, but I managed to see the details. It says `{\"detail\":\"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing.\"}` when printing the responses `.text()` function. I tried using csrf_exempt decorator, but it doesn't work @Igonato

Comment: I just checked and I get the same output when not including `Api-Key ` in the `Authorization` header, so this must be some sort of `rest_framework_api_key` bug

Comment: It is something with the web! I downloaded Postman and it worked perfectly. Now I need to figure out what to do in the web

Comment: If you're not using a cookie based auth, it's safe to disable the csrf protection entirely. Weird that the decorator didn't work though...

Comment: Placement may matter. Swap it with the api_view one, see if that helps

Comment: Wait I got it to work!! I deleted the cookies, the session and the csrftoken and it just worked. I guess that's why it worked on Postman - it didn't have a csrftoken. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a CSRF exemption permission class or decorator, e.g.:

`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

and above your API view declaration:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
def tts_view(request):
```

With this, ensuring that you pass in your DRF API token in headers in your API call as
`Authorization: Token token_string`
should suffice.

Comment: It is still not working, but thanks!